# Same GraphQL query on production (which gives me what I want), results in 504 time-out locally

Tags: graphql

I have 2 identical installs local and production. Both servers are nearly identical and when checking Utilities > System Report all requirements are met.

When I query for matrix blocks locally, I get to see a 504 time-out. While on production the result is almost instantly there.

I don't know what is causing this. Other local queries are being executed just fine. Does this have to do with server settings, Craft config settings or something else? I'm kind of in the dark here.